# Error when setting OnClickListener in android

Tags: android

I'm beginner in android and I wrote the following simple program that just shows the text of the button I press on a TextView (I always get a runtime error):

```
package com.hmz.secondapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AppPageActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnPlus;
    Button btnMinus;
    Button btnMul;
    Button btnDiv;

    TextView resultTextView;

    View.OnClickListener operations = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Button pressedButton = (Button) v;

            String buttonLabel = pressedButton.getText().toString();

            resultTextView.setText(buttonLabel);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.app_page);

        btnPlus.setOnClickListener(operations);
        btnMinus.setOnClickListener(operations);
        btnMul.setOnClickListener(operations);
        btnDiv.setOnClickListener(operations);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.app_page, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your btnPlus object is null. You need to instantiate it in the onCreate method like

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.app_page);

    btnPlus  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID);
    btnMinus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID);
    btnMul   = (Button)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID);
    btnDiv   = (Button)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID);

    btnPlus.setOnClickListener(operations);
    btnMinus.setOnClickListener(operations);
    btnMul.setOnClickListener(operations);
    btnDiv.setOnClickListener(operations);
}
```

Also instantiate the resultTextView object before you use setText method.

Answer (score 0):

From your code the problem is seems that you are not initializing the buttons (btnPlus,btnMinus,btnMul,btnDiv) and the TextView resultTextView.

```
btnPlus        = (Button)findViewById(Button Id);
btnMinus       = (Button)findViewById(Button Id);
btnMul         = (Button)findViewById(Button Id);
btnDiv         = (Button)findViewById(Button Id);
resultTextView = (Button)findViewById(TextView Id);
```

First initialize these Views then you can apply any operation on these views like Click Events and setting the text.